# Detect which monitor an SDL window uses

Tags: sdl2

I have some SDL code that, before creating a Window and a Renderer, detects the display DPI using `SDL_GetDisplayDPI`, to properly scale textures late on for different types of monitors (for instance my MacBook Pro's monitor returns a DPI of 258, while my external Dell monitor returns 93).

When I use 2 monitors, `SDL_GetNumVideoDisplays` properly returns 2, but I couldn't find any function in SDL that would get me which monitor the window is running in, to call `SDL_GetDisplayDPI` with the correct index, nor any way to detect when the window is dragged from one monitor to the other.

Is there a way to do those things in SDL, or is there a tutorial somewhere that would explain how to do that (hopefully in a platform-independent way)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want [`SDL_GetWindowDisplayIndex`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowDisplayIndex?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryVideo%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29). It takes in a pointer to your `SDL_Window` and returns the display index where the center of that window lies.

As to handling dragging, you probably have to manually requery this index yourself while handling resize events inside the event loop.

Comment: Is there a way the SDL window in a desired window? Example, can I create a Window in Monitor 2? How to achieve that?

Comment: @programmer Yes, take a look at `SDL_WINDOWPOS_CENTERED_DISPLAY` for an example.